# Change color of org-mode checkboxes

Tags: org-mode, faces, customize

I'd like to change the color of unchecked checkboxes in org-mode. To be exact, I want them to be displayed in the color of TODO keywords.

So I've tried to tackle this using `custom-set-faces` and `:inherit`, but this didn't have any effect:

```
(custom-set-faces '(org-checkbox ((t (:inherit org-todo)))))
```

Any idea how to do this properly?

Comment: Dunno. That looks OK to me. Maybe someone else has better eyesight. Have you started Emacs using `emacs -Q`? Maybe something else changes it later (?). What's the effect - no effect? Better question: Why not just use `M-x customize-face`?

Comment: @Drew Thanks! There was no effect. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Drew was right: in some other part of my `init.el`, I had overwritten `org-todo` with `custom-set-faces`:

```
(custom-set-faces
 '(org-todo ((t (:overline t)))))
```

This seems to reset the `:foreground` property. Instead, I should have used:

```
(face-spec-set 'org-todo '((t (:overline t))))
```

See http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_define_face.html.

Eventually, however, I found an even better way, in my view, to highlight and discern checked and unchecked checkboxes. Based on the proposal [here](https://fuco1.github.io/2017-05-25-Fontify-done-checkbox-items-in-org-mode.html), the checkbox text is colorized rather than the brackets:

[image]

```
(defface org-checkbox-todo-text
    '((t (:inherit org-todo)))
    "Face for the text part of an unchecked org-mode checkbox.")

(font-lock-add-keywords
 'org-mode
 `(("^[ \t]*\\(?:[-+*]\\|[0-9]+[).]\\)[ \t]+\\(\\(?:\\[@\\(?:start:\\)?[0-9]+\\][ \t]*\\)?\\[\\(?: \\|\\([0-9]+\\)/\\2\\)\\][^\n]*\n\\)" 1 'org-checkbox-todo-text prepend))
 'append)

(defface org-checkbox-done-text
    '((t (:inherit org-done)))
    "Face for the text part of a checked org-mode checkbox.")

(font-lock-add-keywords
 'org-mode
 `(("^[ \t]*\\(?:[-+*]\\|[0-9]+[).]\\)[ \t]+\\(\\(?:\\[@\\(?:start:\\)?[0-9]+\\][ \t]*\\)?\\[\\(?:X\\|\\([0-9]+\\)/\\2\\)\\][^\n]*\n\\)" 1 'org-checkbox-done-text prepend))
 'append)
```

Answer (score 0):

you missed the `:foreground nil`,
corrected code snippet according to the requirement

```
(custom-set-faces '(org-checkbox ((t (:foreground nil :inherit org-todo)))))
```